# displaying public and private post of following user

Tags: php, mysql

I am user A and I am following User B then I will see user B private posts. That is all I want to achive.

My current query.

```
SELECT *, `facebook_posts`.post_id AS post_id, facebook_posts.STATUS AS STATUS
FROM `facebook_posts`
INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `facebook_posts`.`user_id`
WHERE users.id = 3
OR facebook_posts.visibility = 'public'
ORDER BY `facebook_posts`.`post_id` DESC
LIMIT 3
```

tables "followings"
following_id
follower_id

table "posts"

user_id
post_id
status
status_image

may be i need to add up another join?

Comment: It's not clear what your actual problem is, what are your current results and what do you want?

Comment: @NigelRen Need to display "followers user private and public post "

Comment: @NigelRenI am user A and I am following User B then I will see user B private posts. That is all I want to achive.